# Programming in c# not working

Tags: programming, c#

I programmed in c # using windows and never had any problems. Since I started using ubuntu I have a problem. the applications (Visual studio code, monodevelop, sublime text and atom) do not show errors in the syntax, I have installed .NET but I cannot get them to work. Any solution?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 20.04 LTS